# HTML table selectable rows Javascript package

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a Javascript package out there that makes table rows selectable/highlightable by clicking on them and using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys?

I'm looking for the same functionality as iTunes or some other music player that allows to highlight one song by clicking the row or highlighting multiple by holding shift or control and clicking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### You can do it without plugins!

This example `highlights` a `row` or multiple ones by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd> *(for MacOS users)* or <kbd>Shift</kbd> keyboard key and clicking.

*I will suggest to avoid plugins for simple things. You will see that this is not a lot of code to implement for what you need to achieve.*

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/ctLm8/2/

---

***HTML:***

Suppose I have the following table (you will interact with the rows).

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Luis</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>$100,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Oscar</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>$90,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Daniel</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>$50,000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

***CSS:***

Now I will create some `CSS` to use the `default` `cursor` when navigating the `table` *(just for styling, you can remove it)* and another one to `highlight` the `row`.

```
tr { cursor: default; }
.highlight { background: yellow; }
```

***jQuery:***

This is all the code you need, please read comments.

```
$(function() {

    /* Get all rows from your 'table' but not the first one 
     * that includes headers. */
    var rows = $('tr').not(':first');

    /* Create 'click' event handler for rows */
    rows.on('click', function(e) {

        /* Get current row */
        var row = $(this);

        /* Check if 'Ctrl', 'cmd' or 'Shift' keyboard key was pressed
         * 'Ctrl' => is represented by 'e.ctrlKey' or 'e.metaKey'
         * 'Shift' => is represented by 'e.shiftKey' */
        if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) || e.shiftKey) {
            /* If pressed highlight the other row that was clicked */
            row.addClass('highlight');
        } else {
            /* Otherwise just highlight one row and clean others */
            rows.removeClass('highlight');
            row.addClass('highlight');
        }

    });

    /* This 'event' is used just to avoid that the table text 
     * gets selected (just for styling). 
     * For example, when pressing 'Shift' keyboard key and clicking 
     * (without this 'event') the text of the 'table' will be selected.
     * You can remove it if you want, I just tested this in 
     * Chrome v30.0.1599.69 */
    $(document).bind('selectstart dragstart', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); return false; 
    });

});
```

Finally, if you insist on creating a plugin, you can take a look at this site and customize  the code for what you need.

http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

*Other functionalities just depend on you, I just answered what you required in the question :-) hope this helps.*

Comment: when I have selected all the rows with `ctrl key`... there is now **mechanism to deselect** the row among the selected ones...  @oscarJara

Comment: just a little editing in the `if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) || e.shiftKey)` block. instead of addClass use toggleClass like below 
`if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) || e.shiftKey) {`
            `row.addClass('highlight');`
        `}`

Comment: Well, as I said, I just answered what was requested but more capabilities can be added for sure @MateeGojra

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery UI [selectable](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/).

You can select multiple itens holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, or you can click a item and drag.

[API Reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/).

[JS Bin Example](http://jsbin.com/UvAkiTE/4/edit).

Comment: how to make it multi selectable?