# How to make my rows within different html tables selectable using PHP?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and currently I am using php to create four different conference tables that have some hard-coded data in for now and I am trying to make any of the rows within the four tables selectable and eventually I will save the rows selected into a database, but for now I just can't figure out a way to make the rows selectable using PHP. Below is the current code that displays the four tables on my localhost. If this is not possible with PHP how would I incorporate another language within a php file to make the rows selectable. Thank you all for your help in advance.

Conference Class:

```
<?php

class Conference
{
    protected $teams;

    function loadTeams($teams)
    {
        $this->teams = $teams;
    }

    function getTeams()
    {
        return $this->teams;
    }
}

?>
```

Main code:

```
<?php print( '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>User selection page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="gameViewStyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>


    <?php   

        require_once('Conference.php'); 

        for ($j = 0; $j<4; $j++)
        {       
            $loadGameClass = new Conference();
            $loadGameClass->loadTeams(array("(1)Gonzaga vs (16)Southern U", "(8)Pittsburgh vs (9)Wichita St", "(5)Wisconsin vs (12)Ole Miss", "(4)Kansas st vs (13)Boise St", "(6)Arizona vs (11)Belmont", "(3)New Mexico vs (14) Harvard", "(7)Notre Dame vs (10)Iowa St", "(2)Ohio St vs (15) Iona"));
            $teams = $loadGameClass->getTeams();

            echo '<table border="1" align="center">';

            switch ($j) {
                case 0:
                    echo "Midwest";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    echo "West";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    echo "South";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    echo "East";
                    break;  
                }

            for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) 
            {
                $games = $teams[$i];
                echo '<tr><td>'.$games.'</td><tr>';
            }

            echo '</table>';
            echo "<br>" . "<br>";


        }
    ?>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by select-able? Do you mean if they are clicked, some additional code is executed or a new page is displayed?

Comment: @James Hi James sorry about not being to clear, within the front-end of the website I would like to be able to click a row and that row is for example toggled or changed to a different color lets go with green and eventually I will have a button at the bottom to save the selected rows into a database.

Comment: First I notice an error in your table, your switch instruction echo a string directly in table element, not in <td> element. It's an error, a well formed <table> element doesn't have data outside a <td> or a <th> element, and th, td can't be outside a tr element... verify on google. I don't know what you really need, but there is another solution proposed by Oscar Jara here (that doesn't need jquery UI selectable as you're trying) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480719/html-table-selectable-rows-javascript-package

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking "selectable" as in front-end interactivity in your browser, that cannot be done with PHP. You need to use JavaScript.

If you just want a link that would tag something as "selected" with a page load and a session value, you could do small form submits for each select/deselect action, and highlight the appropriate rows.

side note: `<br>` is invalid in XHTML - you need to use `<br />`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Collin. So I would have to add Javascript within my PHP code? What if I just want any of the rows that I click on be selected to change the color to green. Eventually I was hoping to be able to make those selected rows to be saved to a database where some other logic will function on it.

Comment: No, javascript is frontend, so it goes in  your HTML (or linked from HTML)